# UNION ALL con tablas con diferentes número dd columnas

Tags: python, mysql, sql

Tengo una tabla con 3 columbas: Nombre, Apellido, Edad. Y quiero unirlo con UNION ALL con otra tabla pero con solo 2 columnas: Nombre, Edad. ¿Como podria unirlas en este caso?

Answer (score 1):

Pues tienes dos opciones:

a) Juntar el nombre y apellido de la primera, y unirlo a la segunda

b) Meter un `NULL` en el apellido de la segunda

En MySQL sería algo así:

a)

```
SELECT CONCAT(nombre,' ',apellido),edad FROM tabla1
UNION ALL
SELECT nombre,edad FROM tabla2;
```

b)

```
SELECT nombre,apellido,edad FROM tabla1
UNION ALL
SELECT nombre,NULL,edad FROM tabla2;
```

Lo importante es que ambas tengan el mismo número de columnas.

Comment: Gracias @David-JP. Funcionó

Comment: [Recuerda validar y votar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) y [Gana +2 de reputación](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/3762/119615)